# TypeScript Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

What's wrong with my function createUser()?
Why I can't put params in Smoke.ts ?

Login.ts :

```
interface User {
  url: string,
  email: string,
}

class Test{ 
async createUser(user: User) {
    await Page.setUrl(user.url);
    await Page.setEmail(user.email);


   
  }
}
```

Smoke.ts

```
test("Smoke Test", async (t) => {
  console.log("Starting test");  
  await Login.createUser(
  "google.com","joe"
  );
```

An error appear : Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

Comment: `createUser()` is expecting a `User` object as parameter. But you're passing two strings. What you want would be `Login.createUser({ url: "google.com", email: "joe" });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method createUser is expecting an object with the following shape:
{
url: string,
email: string,
}

And you are passing a string as first parameter and another string as the second parameter.

you should be passing an object like this:

```
createUser({ 
   url: 'google.com', 
   email: 'joe' 
})
```

BTW why are you using "interface" and not "type" here?
type is more common for defining object shapes and interface is often used to describe behaviours

Answer (score 0):

your createUser function was declared with only one parameter but when you call this method you passed two-parameter.
to fix this you need to pass user object